# issue with screensaver on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, screensaver

I have Windows 8.1 and my screensaver works but only if WMP (the windows media player) is not running.
I have set the time 4 minutes and created a directory with some .jpg. It's often not working when replaying mpeg file with WMP. Some fixing of this is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to follow the following steps to see if the issue can be resolved.

1. Open Windows Media Player
2. Press **ALT** Key
3. Select **Tools**
4. Click on **Options**
5. In the **Player** Tab check the box which says "**Allow Screen Saver during Playback**"
6. Click **Apply** and **OK**

Comment: You are the very best, it works! Thank you so much I've had no hope that this could be resolved.

Comment: @user852508 glad to here it's helpful!

Comment: I have another issue with screensaver: instead of displaying jpg's it from time to time (i.e. once every week) shows **error** with the white small text in Czech language on black background: "nastala chyba pri prehravani prezentace" in the left bottom corner.

Comment: It writes: "This presentation cannot be replayed from the reason of error."